# Search media by title and description - Frontend

Tags: search, media

Have written a function to search by by media title but i also need to search by the description.

Do you know what i should add to my function. here it is:

```
// Media Search Function

function attachment_search( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search ) {
   $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
   $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
}

return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'attachment_search' );


function my_get_attachment_url( $url, $post_id ) {

$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_id );

return $url;
}
add_filter( 'mse_get_attachment_url', 'my_get_attachment_url', 10, 2 );
```